# My CSS is all messed up and will not stay centered

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am making a website, and I cannot get the navigation bar to stay where I want it to be.

This is how it SHOULD look even when viewed on a smaller screen. Please remember we are only talking about the Navigation bar
[image: a busy cat]

This is how it currently looks on a smaller screen

[image: a busy cat]

Finally, here is my code!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

            <html>

            <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">     </script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
                    <style type="text/css">


                            body {

                                margin: 0;
                                background-color: #e0dfcb;
                            }


                            .container {

                                min-width: 800px;
                                height: auto;

                            }

                            #midbar {
                                position: relative;
                                top: -20px;
                                width: 100%;
                                height: 115px;
                                background-color: #e0dfcb;
                                z-index: 1111;  
                                opacity: 0.8;
                            }

                            #midbar img {
                                position: absolute;
                                top: 0px;
                                left:50%;
                                margin-left: -185px;
                                width: 350px;
                                height: 200px;
                                min-height: 50px;
                                min-width: 250px;
                                vertical-align: middle;
                                z-index: 2222;
                            }

                            #navigation {

                                position: absolute;
                                left: 435px;
                                border-top-style: dotted;
                                border-bottom-style: dotted;
                                border-width: 2px;
                                top: 45px;
                            }

                            #navigation ul li   {
                                position: relative;
                                display:inline-block;


                                margin:0 23px 0 0;


                                z-index: 3333;
                            }
                            #navigation ul li a                                 {
                                padding-left:15px;
                                text-decoration: none;
                                text-align: center;
                                padding-right:15px;
                                color:#000000;
                                display:block;
                                font-family: 'Gentium Book Basic', serif;
                                font-size:18px;
                            }

                            #navi {

                                position: absolute;
                                left: 1100px;
                                border-top-style: dotted;
                                border-bottom-style: dotted;
                                border-width: 2px;
                                top: 45px;
                            }

                            #navi ul li {
                                position: relative;
                                display:inline-block;


                                margin:0 23px 0 0;

                                z-index: 3333;
                            }
                            #navi ul li a                                   {
                                padding-left:15px;
                                text-decoration: none;
                                text-align: center;
                                padding-right:15px;
                                color:#000000;
                                display:block;
                                font-family: 'Gentium Book Basic', serif;
                                font-size:18px;
                            }

                            #slideshow{

                                width: 100%;
                                height: 100%;
                            }

                            #slideshow{

                                -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 8s 16 ease-in-out;
                                -moz-animation: cssAnimation 8s 16 ease-in-out;
                                -o-animation: cssAnimation 8s 16 ease-in-out;
                                }
                                @-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
                                from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
                                to { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.3) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
                                }
                                @-moz-keyframes cssAnimation {
                                from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
                                to { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.3) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
                                }
                                @-o-keyframes cssAnimation {
                                from { -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
                                to { -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.3) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
                                }


                            #imgholder {
                                position: relative;
                                top: -150px;
                                width: 100%;
                                height: 500px;
                                overflow: hidden;

                            }

                            #over {

                                width: 500px;
                                height: 200px;
                                background-color: #EEEEEE;
                                position: relative;
                                top: -400px;
                                font-size: 32px;
                                opacity: 0.7;
                            }

                            #over p {

                                position: relative;
                                left: 20px;
                            }









                    </style>


            </head>



            <body>


            <div class='container'>




            <div id='midbar'>

                <section id='navigation'>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='index.php'>About</a></li>
                        <li><a href='index.php'>Designs</a></li>
                        <li><a href='index.php'>Events</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <a href='index.php'><img class='img animated bounceInDown' src='images/logo.png'></a>
                <section id='navi'>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='index.php'>Booths</a></li>
                        <li><a href='index.php'>Holidays</a></li>
                        <li><a href='index.php'>Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
            </div>


            <div id='imgholder'>
                <img id="slideshow" src="images/snow.jpg" alt="Slideshow">

                </div>

            <div id='over'>
                <p> Need help?<br>
                    Contact us now!</p>
                </div>






            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">

            var img1 = new Image();
            img1.src = "images/snow.jpg";

            var img2 = new Image();
            img2.src = "images/water.jpg";

            var img3 = new Image();
            img3.src = "images/othersnow.jpg";

            var img4 = new Image();
            img4.src = "images/cool.jpg";

            var galleryarray = [img1, img2, img3, img4];

            var curimg = 1;
            function rotateimages(){
                $( "#slideshow" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
                    document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", galleryarray[curimg].src)
                    curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0
                });
                $( "#slideshow" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
            }

            window.onload=function(){
                setInterval("rotateimages()", 8000)
            }

            </script>







            </body>
            </html>
```

And the code just for the navigation

```
 #midbar {
                                position: relative;
                                top: -20px;
                                width: 100%;
                                height: 115px;
                                background-color: #e0dfcb;
                                z-index: 1111;  
                                opacity: 0.8;
                            }



#navigation {

                                position: absolute;
                                left: 435px;
                                border-top-style: dotted;
                                border-bottom-style: dotted;
                                border-width: 2px;
                                top: 45px;
                            }

                            #navigation ul li   {
                                position: relative;
                                display:inline-block;


                                margin:0 23px 0 0;


                                z-index: 3333;
                            }
                            #navigation ul li a                                 {
                                padding-left:15px;
                                text-decoration: none;
                                text-align: center;
                                padding-right:15px;
                                color:#000000;
                                display:block;
                                font-family: 'Gentium Book Basic', serif;
                                font-size:18px;
                            }

                            #navi {

                                position: absolute;
                                left: 1100px;
                                border-top-style: dotted;
                                border-bottom-style: dotted;
                                border-width: 2px;
                                top: 45px;
                            }

                            #navi ul li {
                                position: relative;
                                display:inline-block;


                                margin:0 23px 0 0;

                                z-index: 3333;
                            }
                            #navi ul li a                                   {
                                padding-left:15px;
                                text-decoration: none;
                                text-align: center;
                                padding-right:15px;
                                color:#000000;
                                display:block;
                                font-family: 'Gentium Book Basic', serif;
                                font-size:18px;
                            }



<div id='midbar'>

                <section id='navigation'>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='index.php'>About</a></li>
                        <li><a href='index.php'>Designs</a></li>
                        <li><a href='index.php'>Events</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <a href='index.php'><img class='img animated bounceInDown' src='images/logo.png'>  </a>
                <section id='navi'>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='index.php'>Booths</a></li>
                        <li><a href='index.php'>Holidays</a></li>
                        <li><a href='index.php'>Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide an interactive demo? Like jsfiddle.

Comment: This is probably because you center you navigation with the absolute position from the left. As your screen shrink, this number stays the same and your box get squashed. Check out `margin: 0px auto` or CSS3 transform tp center (`position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);`). _When posting here, however, please try to make your code concise and only post enough to just about replicate the problem, don't make us decipher what you wrote._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its becaus your absolute position of the navigation and navi element.

```
left: 1100px;
```

Your .container has a min-width of 800px... optimize the menu for this width and make the container centered.

EDIT:

Overwrite this stylings:

```
#midbar {
  background-color: #e0dfcb;
  height: 115px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  width: 800px;
  z-index: 1111;
}


#navigation {
  border-bottom-style: dotted;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-width: 2px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
}


#navi {
  border-bottom-style: dotted;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-width: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 45px;
}
```

If it is to narrow alter the width in #midbar.

EDIT:2

Ok to keep the tan bar i added another div around the menu:

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/zzfa1m3p/1/

Added:
     in Line 8
     in Line 28

an copied styling from midbar:

```
.top {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 115px;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 1111;  
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Im sorry for being a noob, But could you show me what you mean with my code?

Comment: That code did make it so it goes with the page. But im still at the initial problem. The nav bar elements are supposed to stay close to the logo in the middle like the initial photo. and the tan background is supposed to take up the whole screen.

Comment: When I do this, the tan bar only goes say 800 px, when I enlarge it it still works but then the navi elements are stuck tot he left and the right of the midbar so the move to the edge of the screen instead of staying next to the logo

Comment: I made a fiddle with your code. (normally you should use this for a demo) [http://jsfiddle.net/zzfa1m3p/](http://jsfiddle.net/zzfa1m3p/)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using position absolute with fixed values, these values change depending on the screen size, so it can never be centered on all sizes. I took your code and put it in a JsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ejxj7ghe/ *note this is not responsive to mobiles but will be centered.

Here is what i changed in the CSS

```
#midbar {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 115px;
    background-color: #e0dfcb;
    z-index: 1111;
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#navigation {
    position: relative;
    border-top-style: dotted;
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
    border-width: 2px;
    top: 45px;
    width: 382px;
    float: left;
}

#navi {
    position: relative;
    border-top-style: dotted;
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
    border-width: 2px;
    top: 45px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: check this in one second